# Decompiled DLL - CS1660 Cannot convert to 'Delegate' because type is not of delegate type

Tags: c#, .net, dotpeek

I decompiled a .net 4.6.1 project dll with dotpeek.  After decompiling I have the following error:

CS1660 Cannot convert to 'Delegate' because type is not of delegate type

```
private void MainLogAdd(string s, System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
      this.logcol.Add(color);
      this.lstLogBox.Invoke((delegate) (() =>
      {
        this.lstLogBox.Items.Add((object) ("[" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(0, 8) + "] " + s));
        this.lstLogBox.TopIndex = this.lstLogBox.Items.Count - 1;
      }));
    }
```

After change with new Action 'Action 1 does not contain a constructor that takes its arguments'
[image: ']

Comment: This is a mismash of two syntaxes, each valid separately.  `delegate(typed argument list) { code here }` has been available since C# 2.0, while `(arg names, types optional) => {code here}` was introduced later to allow omitting types that can be inferred.  The first syntax has a different advantage... leaving out the argument list makes it compatible with any argument list.  In the first syntax, parentheses are not allowed around the keyword `delegate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it'll work out if you simply change `(delegate)` to `(Action)` instead

Before:

```
this.lstLogBox.Invoke((delegate) (() =>
```

After:

```
this.lstLogBox.Invoke((Action) (() =>
```

Here's an example:

[image]

### Edit

You say you have a class called Action already and it's causing a conflict. You can use the full name:

```
this.lstLogBox.Invoke((System.Action) (() =>
```

Or you can create an alias by e.g. putting this at the top of your class:

```
using SystemAction = System.Action;
```

Then using the alias..

```
this.lstLogBox.Invoke((SystemAction) (() =>
```

Or you can rename your class :)

Comment: I have a class named Action so ı cant use this delegate Action ı sellect Action<> in list but its sellect my class :(

Comment: Then `System.Action`.  It's possible that the colliding names are somehow related to the decompiler bug, but more likely that the decompiler just has unfinished support for decompiling to lambdas

Comment: Thank you so much Sir

Answer (score 2):

Replace `(delegate)` with `new System.Action`:

```cs
    this.lstLogBox.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        this.lstLogBox.Items.Add((object) ("[" + DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(0, 8) + "] " + s));
        this.lstLogBox.TopIndex = this.lstLogBox.Items.Count - 1;
    }));
```

The `Invoke` method accepts a parameter of type `Delegate`, which is an abstract class and the base type for all delegates.

Lambda expressions may compile to expression trees (`Expression<Func<...>>`) or plain delegates (`Action` or `Func`). The C# compiler needs to know the exact type of the delegate, so it can generate the code for the lambda expression.

By the way, that's the problem with most C# decompilers. I had the best luck with ILSpy.

Comment: I try this but now get another error. I add this error to post

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `.Invoke()` needs to be an actual instantiated delegate type such as `Action` because the Windows Forms library was created before lambdas existed in C#. Instead of casting the lambda to a `delegate` like the decompiler wrote, it should read something like this:

```csharp
this.lstLogBox.Invoke(new Action(() => { ... }));
```

Comment: I try this but now get another error. I add this error to post

Comment: @eray I only see an image with the red underline; what is the actually error it is showing on that line?

Comment: oh mb 'action 1 does not contain a constructor that takes its arguments'

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the correct `Action` type then. It should be `System.Action`.